# Running sdk on android studio

Tags: android, sdk

I am new in android studio and company send me SDK. I am unable to run 
It contain UI components

Steps I took .

1. Importing project in android studio.

And then i found it do not have gradle files
[image]

The files in red are added by me later ( i just copy paste them from another project ) also run button to run app on simulator is disabled. Can any body tell how to make run app from this code ? It is new and i have no idea any insight will also be helpful.

---

Also they are saying me to run app using **SDK tools**.

Answer (score 0):

Red colors generally related with the VCS(version control system) on Android Studio,They mean you have added new file that is not in the scope of git before and that files have not been added to the git.

Try select the file(s) and right click on them , on the dialog there has to be an github row. If you hover it , you can see the "Add" option.(Or just do Ctrl+Alt+A if you are using windows OS).After the proccess succeses the color of the files should be green.

Comment: Problem is not the red colour. App is not running it is saying to add configuration it is the main error